# How to count columns of data that have values between the range of two numbers w/Rails Scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My problem is relatively simple. I am trying to aggregate and count all records of the job model that have values BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000. The problem is my scope is not producing the correct results. I'm receiving the error below

Error

```
  Job Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" GROUP BY count(hourly_wage_salary) BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
LINE 1: SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" GROUP BY count(hourly_wage_sala...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" GROUP BY count(hourly_wage_salary) BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000 LIMIT $1
```

The code for my scope is:

```
scope :count_jobs_with_salaries_between_20k_30k, -> {group("count(hourly_wage_salary) BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000")}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT
FROM JOBS
```

Besides this also works

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JOBS WHERE SALARY BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000;
```

you can check working example from  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1826f/2)

EDIT: **Rails Scope**

```
jobs.where(salary: 10000..20000).count
```

Comment: How do you accomplish this with a scope in Rails?